# How to convert JSON formatted string of data rows of a table in to java array in android

Tags: java, android, json, arrays

I have a JSON string like this of data for a table in an android app. one of {} is a row of data for the table. I want to separate these {}s into an array and then each element inside this array into other sub-arrays separating other elements inside {}. Please suggest an appropriate way of accomplishing this criteria using JSON. Thank you.

```
[
     {
        "nodeName":"prime_mtsc22@smpp3",
        "nodeId":"MTSC3",
        "tidPrefix":"4",
        "optStatus":"offline",
        "daStart":"1",
        "daEnd":"3",
        "description":"Description"
     },
     {
        "nodeName":"prime_mtsc22@smpp2",
        "nodeId":"MTSC58",
        "tidPrefix":"1",
        "optStatus":"blocked",
        "daStart":"5",
        "daEnd":"10",
        "description":"new description"
     },
     {
        "nodeName":"prime_mtsc22@smpp1",
        "nodeId":"MTSC1",
        "tidPrefix":"15",
        "optStatus":"online",
        "daStart":"12",
        "daEnd":"20",
        "description":"Description"
     },
     {
        "nodeName":"prime_mtsc22@smpp0",
        "nodeId":"MTSC15",
        "tidPrefix":"15",
        "optStatus":"offline",
        "daStart":"25",
        "daEnd":"30",
        "description":"Description"
     }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok so in that case the code to use is this

```
String jsonString = <your jsonString>;

// THIS IS NOT NEEDED ANYMORE 
//JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonString);

JSONArray topArray = null; 
try {
     // Getting your top array

     // THIS IS NOT NEEDED ANYMORE 
     //topArray = json.getJSONArray(jsonString);

     //use this instead
     topArray = new JSONArray(jsonString);

      // looping through All elements
      for(int i = 0; i < topArray.length(); i++){
      JSONObject c = topArray.getJSONObject(i);

      //list holding row data
      List<NodePOJO> nodeList = new ArrayList<NodePOJO>(); 

      // Storing each json item in variable
      String nodeName = c.getString("nodeName");
      String nodeID = c.getString("nodeID");

      NodePOJO pojo = new NodePOJO();
      pojo.setNodeName(nodeName);
      //add rest of the json data to NodePOJO class

      //the object to list
      nodeList.add(pojo);

    }
} catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
 }
```

ok?

Answer (score 1):

Use JSONObject for this http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html

Example

```
    String jsonString = <your jsonString>;

    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonString);
    JSONObject topArray = ; 
    try {
         // Getting your top array
         topArray = json.getJSONArray(TAG_ARRAY_TOP);

          // looping through All elements
          for(int i = 0; i < topArray.length(); i++){
          JSONObject c = topArray.getJSONObject(i);

          //list holding row data
          List<NodePOJO> nodeList = new ArrayList<NodePOJO>(); 

          // Storing each json item in variable
          String nodeName = c.getString("nodeName");
          String nodeID = c.getString("nodeID");

          NodePOJO pojo = new NodePOJO();
          pojo.setNodeName(nodeName);
          //add rest of the json data to NodePOJO class

          //the object to list
          nodeList.add(pojo);

        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
     }
```

Use the NodePOJO class to hold each row values.

```
 public class NodePOJO {
    private String nodeName;
    // do for rest of the json row data
    public void setNodeName(String nodeName) {
          this.nodeName = nodeName;
    }
    public String getNodeName() {
         return this.nodeName;
    }
 }
```

Comment: Please tell me what is TAG_ARRAY_TOP and what should I use for it?

Comment: the piece of JSON you've posted is part of an array ([ <- this is the start of an array in JSON). you should have a JSON tag before the **[** for instance **"contacts":** [ 

TAG_ARRAY_TOP is a string that represents that JSON tag.
Ok?

Comment: but there is no such tag for the above string as it is taken as a response from a web server !