# Compare JSON data with Table data

Tags: sql-server, json, automated-tests, bigdata

Got a requirement to Automate the data compare 
between JSON and Table Sql server. any ideas or views please..

Comment: check here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12686530/how-to-convert-json-formatted-string-of-data-rows-of-a-table-in-to-java-array-in)

Answer (score 0):

Well your description isn't very specific but by json data I guess you refer to the data returned by some API?

In that case, I would do following

1. Use Nunit (if it is c#). Why? Because everyone does that (i.e good documentation and a proven framework). Some people use TestNg and that works for them.
2. Copy the models from the source code (ask your devs).
3. Create sql queries for fetching the data from your db.
4. Instantiate an entity based on the models you copied and populate it with the values fetched from the database.
5. Instantiate an entity based on the jsonbody you get in the api response.

E.g

```
        var jsonEntity = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Entity>(json);
        Assert.AreEqual(databaseEntity.name, jsonEntity.Name);
```

Restsharp is very easy to use if you don't want to create your own rest client.

If you want a more specific answer on how I would do things please provide a more specific description.